# Rust at the bottom of water heater - ok to continue using?

Tags: water-heater

Might be a silly question, blame it on a brand new newborn and not sleeping at all.

I have a water heater that has some rust around the bottom of it. I’m fairly sure this is due to occasional water coming out of the pressure release valve when it overpressurizes. The heater itself was installed 3 or 4 years ago, there’s no discoloration or taste issues with the water, and it is able to efficiently heat up water quietly.

If it’s just rust on the outside, is it still fine to use or do I need to replace the whole unit?

Thanks all!

Comment: so only some exterior rust

Comment: attach a pice of garden hose to the overpressure valve outlet to lead the water way

Comment: Gas fired or not, it's still a dupe because the important part is **when you're ok with three days of no hot water**. 3~4yo? You got another 5y before that's a concern. [Rust in gas flame area of water heater, should be replaced?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/49710/rust-in-gas-flame-area-of-water-heater-should-be-replaced) - It's less than a four hour job. After the four week backlog it takes for a guy to show up.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no rust on the outside of a water heater; sounds like a small leak somewhere. Possibly the safety valve.